# How do I write a Screenlet?

Tags: 11.04, programming, screenlets

I'm trying to write a screenlet. It should basically just display a background (could be generated in screenlet or svg) and display some text.

I know about the template screenlet and [documentation](http://screenlets.org/index.php/Documentation#Developers), but even the template screenlet doesn't work for me.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and screenlets from the software centre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably get your answer on launchpad answers (For the screenlets project): https://answers.launchpad.net/screenlets