# How to create my own screenlet

Tags: 12.04, screenlets

I am using 1 year ubuntu as my main OS already and I feel comfortable with the enviroment and the tools it provides. I also used one screenlet to have my task manager or calendar on my desktop and have it connected directly with google calendar in order to track my todos.

But now I would like to make my own screen-let since I can't find one that will help me orgnize my stuff better, like a small little browser that fetches some webdata, or load a small html client in a screenlet. I am not sure how to start and I can't find any documentation on how to make my own. I have found this post but the documentation does not seem to work [How do I write a Screenlet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41636/how-do-i-write-a-screenlet)
Are screenlets dead and about to be substituted by something else?
I am using ubuntu 12.04 at the moment on an Intel core I7.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenlets.org website is down, probably because it was unmaintained and had lots of spam. Currently you can find documentation in the Web Archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20130314075629/http://screenlets.org/index.php/Documentation